# How to get puppeteer working in Google Cloud Run/Cloud Build?

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer, google-cloud-run

I have a docker image containing a puppeteer web scraper.  It works perfectly in my local machine when I build and run it.  It also build fine in cloud build, deploys to cloud run and starts the http server.  However, when I run one of the cron jobs dealing with a puppeteer instance, it times out with this error message:

```
(node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome! The only Chrome revision guaranteed to work is r706915
```

Full log:

```
A 2019-12-03T15:12:27.748625Z (node:13) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to Chrome! The only Chrome revision guaranteed to work is r706915 
A 2019-12-03T15:12:27.748692Z     at Timeout.onTimeout (/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:359:14) 
A 2019-12-03T15:12:27.748705Z     at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11) 
A 2019-12-03T15:12:27.748716Z     at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5) 
A 2019-12-03T15:12:27.748726Z     at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5) 
A 2019-12-03T15:12:27.748734Z     at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

This error happens directly on the puppeteer `puppeteer.launch()` function.

I have tried to increase memory in the instance, different dockerfile setups (all from googling), different puppeteer instance arguments and try catching in prod.

I was using this as a base docker image (https://github.com/buildkite/docker-puppeteer), but it wasn't working so I decided to modify it for my own liking, and this is what I have so far:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:10.15

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y wget --no-install-recommends \
  && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst ttf-freefont \
  --no-install-recommends \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y curl \
  && rm -rf /src/*.deb

# RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
# RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# Copy package.json to docker image
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy source code of dir to image
COPY . .


ARG DOCKER_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}


EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

`openBrowserInstance.js`

```
const randomUserAgent = require(__dirname + '/randomUserAgent');
const randomProxy = require(__dirname + '/../multiple/randomProxy');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let defaultOptions = {
    blockStyleAssets: true,
    viewport: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    },
    urls: [''],
    screenshotPath: null,
    callback: null,
    randomUserAgent: true,
    randomProxy: true
};

module.exports = ( options, callback ) => {
    return new Promise( async( resolve ) => {

        options = Object.assign({}, defaultOptions, options);

        // Required options
        if ( options.urls.length < 1 || typeof callback === 'undefined' ) {
            console.log('Missing one or more required options for "openBrowserInstance.js".');
            resolve();
            return;
        }

        let browserOptions = {
            args: [`--proxy-server=http://${randomProxy()}`,'--lang=en-GB',
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage'],
            headless: true
        };

        const browser = await puppeteer.launch( browserOptions );
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.authenticate({username:'abrCKs', password:'ge2kCw'});

        page.viewport( options.viewport );


        if ( options.blockStyleAssets ) {

            await page.setRequestInterception(true);

            page.on('request', (req) => {

                let resourceType = req.resourceType();

                if (resourceType === 'image' || resourceType === 'stylesheet') {
                    req.abort();
                } else {
                    req.continue();
                }

            });

        }

        for (const [index, url] of options.urls.entries()) {

            let userAgent = null;

            if ( options.randomUserAgent ) {

                userAgent = randomUserAgent();

                await page.setUserAgent( userAgent );
            }

            await page.goto( url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' } );

            let pageContent = await page.content();

            await callback(pageContent, url, index);

            await page.close();

        }

        if ( options.screenshotPath !== null ) {
            await page.screenshot({path: screenshotPath, fullPage: true});
        }
        await browser.close();

        resolve();
    })
};
```

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/git'
  args: ['clone', 'GIT-REPO-PLACEHOLDER']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--build-arg', 'DOCKER_ENV=dev', '-t', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/PROJECT-NAME-PLACEHOLDER', '.']
  dir: 'PROJECT-NAME-PLACEHOLDER/'

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/PROJECT-NAME-PLACEHOLDER']

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['beta', 'run', 'deploy', 'PROJECT-NAME-PLACEHOLDER', '--image', 'eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/PROJECT-NAME-PLACEHOLDER', '--region', 'europe-west1','--platform', 'managed', '--quiet', '--memory', '2G']

images:
- eu.gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/PROJECT-NAME-PLACEHOLDER
```

Please let me know if you have any recommendations.  I have also looked into Google Cloud Functions for this purpose but I wasn't sure if that would work either.  If I cannot find a solution, I will be forced to run this on a VM instance, which is hilariously full circle..

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://github.com/as-a-service/screenshot/ has an example for Cloud Run. More at https://github.com/steren/awesome-cloudrun.

Answer (score 15):

Here is a fully functional sample running Puppeteer on Cloud Run:

`screenshot.js`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

exports.screenshot = async (req, res) => {
    const url = req.query.url;

    if (!url) {
      return res.send('Please provide URL as GET parameter, for example: <a href="?url=https://example.com">?url=https://example.com</a>');
    }

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    const imageBuffer = await page.screenshot();
    browser.close();

    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    res.send(imageBuffer);
  };
```

`server.js`:

```
'use strict';

const {screenshot} = require('./screenshot.js')

const express = require('express');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const app = express();

app.use(screenshot);

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, err => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.info(`App listening on port ${port}`);
  });

module.exports = app;
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "screenshot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Takes screenshot of the given URL.",
  "author": "Steren",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "puppeteer": "^1.10.0"
  }
}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:10

# Adds required libs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 \
    libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 \
    ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget

# Start the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: The "--no-sandbox" arg is recommended against.

Answer (score 7):

So after an entire day of debugging the answer was right here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker

```
FROM node:10-slim

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
# ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /node_modules

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

CMD ["google-chrome-unstable"]
```

Comment: Slightly different from the reference code in above link. The code in the link works, but you code get some error when builds

Comment: What was the answer? You just pasted the code, can you provide an explanation of why it worked?

Answer (score 1):

After a number of attempts, I was able to deploy to Google Cloud Run with this Dockerfile and `puppeteer~17.1.3` because newer versions have more browser requirements.

```
# Ubuntu has support for many frameworks
FROM ubuntu


# Install Node & NPM
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
# Fixing NPM to work
RUN npm i -g npm@latest
RUN npm i -g node-gyp


# Install Google Chrome
RUN apt install chromium-browser -y
RUN apt update 
# Install Puppeteer
RUN npm install -g puppeteer --unsafe-perm=true -allow-root
RUN apt install -y gconf-service libgbm-dev libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget


WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN npm install --production


EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: What is `--unsafe-perm=true -allow-root`?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a complete example, which has actually worked well in the Cloud Run Job.

Deckerfile:

(attention---line 45 "RUN npm init -y && npm i puppeteer" must be commented)

```
# Use the official lightweight Node.js 16 image.
FROM node:16-slim

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure copying both package.json AND package-lock.json (when available).
# Copying this first prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
# If you add a package-lock.json, speed your build by switching to 'npm ci'.
# RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
# ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.2/dumb-init_1.2.2_x86_64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
# RUN npm init -y && npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
RUN groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /usr/src/app/node_modules \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /usr/src/app/package.json \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /usr/src/app/package-lock.json

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser

# Set container environment variable.
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Run the job on container.
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start" ]
```

package.json:

```
{
  ***********
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "puppeteer": "^15.3.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2"
  }
}
```