# Puppeteer can run on Docker locally, but not on Cloud Run (Puppeteer + Cloud Run)

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-platform, puppeteer, google-cloud-run

I am running Puppeteer to convert a template HTML to PDF to be saved on Google Cloud Storage. This is my code snippet to do that.

```
  const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
  const fs = require('fs')
  const path = require('path')

  static async getCertificate(req) {
    const { id: userProgressId } = req.params
    try {
      // Some logic to handle existing certificate (omitted)

      const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, './sample_html.html')
      const html = compileCertificateTemplateHtml('certificate_template.hbs') // This will generate HTML as string (working as intended and tested)
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: 'new',
        args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--no-sandbox'],
      })
      const page = await browser.newPage()
      await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
      const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
        landscape: true,
        printBackground: true,
        width: 681,
      })

      // Some logic to save buffer to cloud (omitted)
    } catch (e) {
      // Some logic to handle errors (omitted)
    }
  }
```

Initially, running this code on Docker doesn't work because Chrome (or Chromium) wasn't installed. To install that, I followed the [troubleshooting section from Puppeteer here](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker). After modifying my Dockerfile to the following, I can run the backend service on my local Docker Engine. Tried hitting the endpoint and it returns the expected result.

```
FROM node:16

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-stable'})
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "./bin/www" ]
```

However, when I built an image using Cloud Build and deployed it to Cloud Run, hitting the same endpoint returned the initial error message (when I didn't write instructions to install the dependencies required to run Headless Chrome in Dockerfile). The error message is specifically the following.

```
Could not find Chrome (ver. 113.0.5672.63). This can occur if either\n 1. you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. `npm install`) or\n 2. your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /home/.cache/puppeteer).\nFor (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration.
```

I looked for other similar issues and tried them locally, but none of them worked even locally (I didn't bother trying them on Cloud Run). Here are some other alternatives I have tried.

- [How to get puppeteer working in Google Cloud Run/Cloud Build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59160869/how-to-get-puppeteer-working-in-google-cloud-run-cloud-build)
- [Chromium inside docker image on Google Cloud Run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861081/chromium-inside-docker-image-on-google-cloud-run)
- [Puppeteer not working in google cloud functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74907113/puppeteer-not-working-in-google-cloud-functions)

In case this is needed, this is my `.yaml` file to build the image on Cloud Run.

```
...
default:
  image: google/cloud-sdk:alpine

.before_staging_script_template:
  before_script:
    - gcloud config set project $STAGING_GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account
      --key-file $STAGING_GCP_SERVICE_KEY

.before_production_script_template:
  before_script:
    - gcloud config set project $PRODUCTION_GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account
      --key-file $PRODUCTION_GCP_SERVICE_KEY

#### STAGING
staging_build:
  stage: build
  extends: .before_staging_script_template
  script:
    - gcloud builds submit
      --tag gcr.io/$STAGING_GCP_PROJECT_ID/$STAGING_SERVICE_NAME
  only:
    - staging
  when: manual
...
```

What should I do to make Puppeteer run successfully on the Docker Engine in Cloud Run?

Comment: Did you run the container locally? Or only the code? I think the problem is the 2nd item proposed by the error trace: the /home should not exist with Cloud Run.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Locally, the Docker container. Specifically, I ran these two commands: `docker build . --tag backend`, then `docker run -p 8080:8080 -d backend`.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I did want to check if the `/home/.cache/puppeteer` exists in the Cloud Run, but we can't SSH into the containers run there AFAIK.

Comment: Yes correct, I also checked that... And yes no SSH. Can you try to deploy your service on the 2nd gen execution runtime? https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/execution-environments

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Done, the same error still occurs: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/39771732?key=53966840754892c40b95b1a3742aecb4

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere While reading around, I did find out that Puppeteer mentions something about the home directory not being found in some cases (https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#could-not-find-expected-browser-locally). In that case, the directory might have to be changed.  Puppeteer seems to promote creating a config file here: https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration, but as mentioned in my question, I added  that config file and it caused the same error in my local container for that endpoint. I didn't bother trying to run it on Cloud Run though.